# Números Hexadecimais ao contrário

Tags: java, c++

Como imprimir os números hexadecimais digitados pelo usuário ao contrário? Por exemplo:

```
Entrada: 0x101c4701
Saída:   01471C10
```

Se possível em Java e em C++.

Na realidade eu quero pegar as informações contidas dentro de um arquivo do registro do Windows que estão assim:

```
"0000"=hex:0x001c2701
"0001"=hex:0x001d2701
```

Queria um código que pegasse somente os 0x001c2701 e invertesse para: 01271c00
o código que vocês me forneceram funciona,mas eu teria que copiar de um em um e como são muitos seria trabalhoso.

Comment: Qual a relação da saída com a entrada? Seria a representação decimal desse hex **literalmente** ao contrário? Pergunto porque converter esses hex pra decimal nem de perto resultam na mesma idéia.

Comment: Sim, Bruno seria o hex, ao contrário.

Comment: Só perguntei pra deixar evidente. Então é apenas manipulamento básico de strings, sem necessidade de conversão.

Comment: Bruno, seria pegar estes hex assim: 0x401c1701 0x011d1701 0x431e1701 0x991f1701 e inverte-los para que fiquem assim: 01171C40 01171D01 01171E43 01171F99, mas eu preciso fazer isso de uma só vez e não de um em um, pediria ao usuario para inserir todos, e retornar a inversão de todos eles.

Comment: Eu notei que durante a aceitação você primeiro aceitou a minha resposta e depois a do Oeslei. Não sei se você sabe que a aceitação, ao contrário do voto, só pode ser feita para uma resposta em cada pergunta. E a aceitação fica na última que você clicar. Não sei se sua intenção foi realmente escolher a resposta do Oeslei, que é uma boa resposta, não teria problema algum em aceitá-la, ou escolher a minha. Não importa qual você escolhe, a decisão é sua, mas é importante entender o funcionamento da ferramenta e fazer uma escolha de acordo com sua vontade real.

Comment: @bigown, Realmente as duas respostas foram excelentes como sou novato aqui não sabia dessa regra, obrigado por me esclarecer vou prestar atenção nas próximas vezes.Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @bigown, poderia me explicar como eu poderia fazer desta forma Entrada:"0000"=hex:40,1c,17,01
"0001"=hex:01,1d,17,01
"0002"=hex:43,1e,17,01 Saida: <01171c40 0171d01 01171e43>.

Comment: Está me parecendo que isto é outra pergunta.

Comment: @bigown, so não fiz pois achei que seria uma pergunta duplicada. ja que esta dentro do assunto da pergunta ja feita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Java dá pra fazer desta forma:

```
String input = "0x101c4701";
String result = "";

for (int i = input.length(); i > 3; i -= 2) {
    result += input.substring((i - 2), i);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Essencialmente dá para usar a mesma solução para ambos.

```
int numero = 0x101c4701;
int invertido swapped = ((numero >> 24) & 0xff) | // move byte 3 p/ byte 0
                        ((numero << 8) & 0xff0000) | // move byte 1 p/ byte 2
                        ((numero >> 8) & 0xff00) | // move byte 2 p/ byte 1
                        ((numero << 24) & 0xff000000) // byte 0 p/ byte 3
```

Este é o princípio da inversão. Como você não colocou o código do que já fez, não sei o que mais você pode precisar.

Veja como converter com o método [`Integer.toHexString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) e o [`Long.parseLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).

Se você quer inverter uma *string*, seria algo assim em Java:

```
String s = "101c4701";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <=s.length()-2; i=i+2) {
    result.append(new StringBuilder(s.substring(i,i+2)).reverse());
 }
System.out.println(result.reverse().toString());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ReverseHex.java).

Conforme [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18831205/221800).

E em C++:

```
std::string reverse_pairs(std::string const & src) {
    assert(src.size() % 2 == 0);
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(src.size());
    for (std::size_t i = src.size(); i != 0; i -= 2) {
        result.append(src, i - 2, 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ReverseHex.cpp).

Conforme [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21410362/221800).